# Как сделать сквозную авторизацию от vk,google,twitter и т.д. на node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Задача: на стороннем сервисе должен подключаться определенный функционал, но быть недоступным без авторизации. Как сделать авторизацию на стороннем ресурсе, но чтобы она проходила для сервера?

P.S.: Такое реализовано в hypercomments. Сервис будет использовать Socket.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь библиотекой [Passport](http://passportjs.org/), либо сервисами наподобие [uLogin](https://ulogin.ru/). Первый вариант более независим, а второй не требует отдельной регистрации вашего приложения/сайта в каждом социальном сервисе.

---

Вообще говоря, это называется социальная аутентификация(Social Authentication). Сервис-провайдеры(те самые vk, google, twitter и т.д.) предоставляют сторонним ресурсам некий способ подтверждения личности зарегистрированного у них пользователя:

1. OpenID - открытый, стандартизированный протокол аутентификации. Работа с ним универсальна и  достаточно легко реализуема.

   Однако в последнее время его популярность резко упала, в связи с нахождением нескольких критических уязвимостей в архитектуре.
2. Псевдоаутентификация через OAuth. Сам OAuth изначально не предоставляет средств для аутентификация пользователей на других ресурсах - он даёт пользователю некого сервиса(провайдера) возможность предоставлять внешним приложениям ограниченные права на использование API сервиса в контексте этого самого пользователя. Однако многие сервисы предоставляют API возвращающие уникальный ID и/или Email пользователя - их то сайты/приложения и используют для аутентификация.

   OAuth относительно сложен сам по себе, требует обязательной регистрации приложения/сайта у провайдера, да и API везде разные - под каждого провайдера приходится писать отдельный код, производящий аутентификацию пользователей.
3. Проприетарные протоколы аутентификации - абсолютно всевозможные способы, к которым только могла прийти фантазия разработчиков.

В связи с многообразием, реализовывать эти механизмы аутентификации самостоятельно очень трудозатратно. Чисто для целей аутентификации, гораздо лучше воспользоватся готовыми библиотеками или сервисами.

Comment: Обычно такие сервисы дают возможность аутентифицировать человека только на сайте с определенным доменом, но т.к. авторизация будет происходить грубо говоря на сайтах, которые не относятся к основному домену, а лишь будут использовать с него скрипт, то проблема как раз остается. Нужно идентифицировать человека именно на стороннем ресурсе, а не на том, который предлагает услуги.

Comment: @МаксимВласов, не совсем понял задачу. Можете пересказать другими словами, в качестве пользовательской истории, например?

Comment: видели как происходит авторизация у hypercomments.com? Т.е. подключается виджет с моего сервиса. И пользователь должен авторизироваться именно в виджете, но независимо от сайта, где он установлен. Т.е. до авторизации именно в виджете он (виджет) не доступен.

Comment: @МаксимВласов, Перед написанием ответа я заходил на hypercomments - и увидел там обычную социальную аутентификацию([скриншот](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eerui.png)) по нажатию кнопки "войти". И да, по умолчанию их виджет доступен всегда, даже вообще не аутентифицированным пользователям. Что вы имеете ввиду - абсолютно непонятно :(

Comment: Да. Обычная авторизация, но без нее нельзя оставить комментарий. Т.е. функционал ограничен([скриншот](http://joxi.ru/RmzQq3ZfwbyErO)). Как это сразу нельзя было заметить? Вопрос и был в том, что как сделать авторизацию именно в виджете по средствам социальных сетей отдельно от авторизации на сайте.